# Is !! a best practice to check a truthy value in an if statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, truthiness

In angular.js, there are some code snippets use `!!` to check whether a value is truthy in if condition.

Is it a best practice? I fully understand in return value or other assignment !! is used to make sure the type is Boolean. But is it also true for condition checks?

```js
if (!!value) {
  element[name] = true;
  element.setAttribute(name, lowercasedName);
} else {
  element[name] = false;
  element.removeAttribute(lowercasedName);
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @Nir This doesn't answer

Comment: this is certainly not best practice, if anything it's a bad practice because it confuses readers and does not have any practical use.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, `!!` is totally useless in a `if` condition and only confuses the reader.

Values which are translated to `true` in `!!value` also pass the `if` test because they're the values that are evaluated to `true` in a Boolean context, they're called ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

So just use

```
if (value) {
```

Comment: Yes, it's useless in javascript.

Comment: Agreed w/r/t control flow, but there is use in doing this in the context of a strongly typed system, such as Flow or TypeScipt. I.e. in cases where a function's signature strictly necessitates a `boolean` type.

Comment: @IliasT There are often cases where you *need* a boolean, even in JavaScript. You may also want to provide a boolean to an API managed by somebody's else because it's cleaner and it lets you not have to check how the value is interpreted. When  I say it's useless I'm only specifically referring to the use in a `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 60):

`!!value` is commonly used as a way to coerce `value` to be either `true` or `false`, depending on whether it is truthy or falsey, respectively.

In a control flow statement such as `if (value) { ... }` or `while (value) { ... }`, prefixing `value` with `!!` has no effect, because the control flow statement is already, by definition, coercing the `value` to be either `true` or `false`.  The same goes for the condition in a ternary operator expression `value ? a : b`.

Using `!!value` to coerce `value` to `true` or `false` is idiomatic, but should of course only be done when it isn't made redundant by the accompanying language construct.

Comment: This is a better answer then the other one which states that it is totally useless. As you point out, there is a use case for those rare times when you do need to coerce the expression to `true` or `false`, for example when a function expects a boolean argument.

Comment: @SunilD. Please read the question against : `" in if condition"`.

Comment: Is this a valid/proper use case for **!!**
`const validData = [value1, value2, .....].filter(val => !!val);`
where validData is an array having only the truthy values